# Creating a test method for a function resulted in WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have the following service method

```
public List<Object> init() {

List<Object> listForAutoCompleteAndPicklists = new ArrayList<>();
listForAutoCompleteAndPicklists.add(getCore());
listForAutoCompleteAndPicklists.add(setPickList());
listForAutoCompleteAndPicklists.add(Collections.singletonList(setStudyTypeAndDesign()));
listForAutoCompleteAndPicklists.add(getMonitors());
return listForAutoCompleteAndPicklists;
```

}

with `getCore(), setPickList(),...` as other functions inside the service. Is it possible to test this kind of method? I came up with

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Test init")
void init() {
    List<Object> response;

response = vaultServiceTest.init();
response.add(1, vaultServiceTest.getBasCore());
response.add(2, vaultServiceTest.setPickList());
response.add(3, vaultServiceTest.setStudyTypeAndDesign());
response.add(4, vaultServiceTest.getMonitors());
assertEquals(4, response.size());
```

}

But that resulted in WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test on `init()`should suffice. A test on this public method covers the side effects of the private methods

Comment: The point is, I don't know how to make a Unit test because there's no API. I'm fairly new to testing and all the methods I've previously tested were with API. All those methods are protected, not private if that matters.